# Elegant way to merge many duplicated columns in R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that I need to merge in R. I can't really modify them before the merge, and they share many columns, but there are no overlapping values in the duplicated columns, if one row in one column has a value then the same row in the duplicated column is NA. After the merge, I have something that looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                  Var1 = c(1,2,NA,NA),
                  Var2 = c("a","b",NA,NA))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
                  Var1 = c(NA,NA,3,4),
                  Var2 = c(NA,NA,"c","d"))

mergedData <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id")

mergedData <- mergedData[, c("Var1.x", "Var1.y", "Var2.x", "Var2.y")]

print(mergedData)
  Var1.x Var1.y Var2.x Var2.y
1      1     NA      a   <NA>
2      2     NA      b   <NA>
3     NA      3   <NA>      c
4     NA      4   <NA>      d
```

I wrote a function to use in other scripts that merges two columns and then removes one of them:

```
mergeColumns <- function(df, colToRemove, colToKeep) {
  df[[colToKeep]][is.na(df[[colToKeep]])] <- df[[colToRemove]][is.na(df[[colToKeep]])]
  df[[colToRemove]] <- NULL
  names(df)[names(df) %in% colToKeep] <- gsub(".x|.y", "", names(df)[names(df) %in% colToKeep])
  return(df)
}
```

This works fine (although I'm sure there is a cleaner approach) when working with single columns. However, in my merged dataframe I have many columns that need to be merged. I am not sure of the best way to do this. I thought about creating a dataframe of the columns that need to be merged and tried using the apply family of functions with no success (I sort of knew the approach below was unlikely to work but thought it might get me going in the right direction):

```
duplicatedColumns <- data.frame(colstoKeep = c("Var1.x", "Var2.x'"),
                                coltoRemove = c("Var1.y", "Var2.y"))

lapply(data, mergeColumns(duplicatedColumns$sampleIntakeCols, duplicatedColumns$rnaMetadataCols))
>Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

Any insight into how I might be able to get this to work of a better approach would be much appreciated. Base R would be preferable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide an example of your data frames before the merge, and the code used to merge them.  The duplicate columns may be being created because the merge is mis-specified.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), as Ritchie suggested, again, please provide the codes you used to create `mergedData` dataframe.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento, updated the first part of my post to include sample dataframes and how they are merged. I want to merge the Var1.x + Var1.y columns and the Var2.x + Var2.y columns by replacing the NA values in one with non-NA values in the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you need to recursively modify the dataframe, I’d just use a good old-fashioned loop. You can also use `grep()` to identify the columns.

```
colstoKeep <- grep("\\.x$", names(mergedData), value = TRUE)
colstoRemove <- grep("\\.y$", names(mergedData), value = TRUE)

for (i in seq_along(colstoKeep)) {
  mergedData <- mergeColumns(mergedData, colstoKeep[[i]], colstoRemove[[i]])
}
mergedData
```

```
  Var1 Var2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    1    c
4    2    d
```